# Mui-x Datepicker different behaviour from local to production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having issues using Datepicker from MUI-X.

Locally all is working correctly but when I deploy on the server the component shows differently.

My component is:

```
import { Done } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker';
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider';
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import 'dayjs/locale/it';
import { useField } from 'formik';

export default function CustomDatePickerField(props) {
    const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(props);
    const { label, placeholder, required, errorMaxDate } = props;

    const { setValue } = helpers;

    return (
        <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="it">
            <DatePicker
                {...props}
                {...field}
                onChange={(newValue) => {
                    setValue(dayjs(newValue), false);
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => {
                    return (
                        <TextField
                            {...params}
                            label={label}
                            required={required}
                            InputLabelProps={{
                                sx: {
                                    color: field.value && 'primary.main',
                                    fontWeight: field.value && 600,
                                },
                            }}
                            InputProps={{
                                ...params.InputProps,
                                sx: {
                                    '& fieldset': {
                                        borderColor: field.value && 'primary.main',
                                        borderWidth: field.value && 2,
                                    },
                                },
                                endAdornment: (
                                    <>
                                        {field.value && <Done color="success" />}
                                        {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                                    </>
                                ),
                            }}
                            helperText={
                                meta.touched && meta.error
                                    ? meta.error === 'maxDate'
                                        ? errorMaxDate
                                        : meta.error
                                    : params.error
                                    ? errorMaxDate
                                    : ''
                            }
                        />
                    );
                }}
            />
        </LocalizationProvider>
    );
}
```

When I see in the inspector the rendered html is:

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root css-1u3bzj6-MuiFormControl-root-MuiTextField-root"><label
        class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary MuiFormLabel-filled MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined css-1t5hpzq-MuiFormLabel-root-MuiInputLabel-root"
        data-shrink="true" for=":r29:" id=":r29:-label">Data di nascita</label>
    <div
        class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-adornedEnd css-u5s1z3-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root">
        <input aria-invalid="false" id=":r29:" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" type="tel"
            class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd css-1nyojts-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input"
            value="12/05/1970"><svg
            class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-colorSuccess MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-h0uysn-MuiSvgIcon-root"
            focusable="false" aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="DoneIcon">
            <path d="M9 16.2 4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"></path>
        </svg>
        <div
            class="MuiInputAdornment-root MuiInputAdornment-positionEnd MuiInputAdornment-outlined MuiInputAdornment-sizeMedium css-1laqsz7-MuiInputAdornment-root">
            <button
                class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-edgeEnd MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-1yq5fb3-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root"
                tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Choose date, selected date is 12 mag 1970"><svg
                    class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-i4bv87-MuiSvgIcon-root" focusable="false"
                    aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="CalendarIcon">
                    <path
                        d="M17 12h-5v5h5v-5zM16 1v2H8V1H6v2H5c-1.11 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L3 19c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-1V1h-2zm3 18H5V8h14v11z">
                    </path>
                </svg><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-8je8zh-MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button></div>
        <fieldset aria-hidden="true"
            class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline css-1d3z3hw-MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline">
            <legend class="css-14lo706"><span>Data di nascita</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when I deploy the html looks like that:

```
<div class="MuiFormControl-root MuiTextField-root css-i44wyl"><label
        class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined MuiFormLabel-colorPrimary MuiFormLabel-filled MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated MuiInputLabel-shrink MuiInputLabel-outlined css-1ww17fv"
        data-shrink="true" for=":r14:" id=":r14:-label">Data di nascita</label>
    <div
        class="MuiInputBase-root MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary MuiInputBase-formControl MuiInputBase-adornedEnd css-16tb7cc">
        <input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" id=":r14:" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" inputmode="text"
            class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-inputAdornedEnd css-6bpnaz"
            value="03/02/1978">
        <div
            class="MuiInputAdornment-root MuiInputAdornment-positionEnd MuiInputAdornment-outlined MuiInputAdornment-sizeMedium css-1nvf7g0">
            <button
                class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-edgeEnd MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-slyssw"
                tabindex="0" type="button" aria-label="Choose date, selected date is 3 feb 1978"><svg
                    class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium css-vubbuv" focusable="false" aria-hidden="true"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24" data-testid="CalendarIcon">
                    <path
                        d="M17 12h-5v5h5v-5zM16 1v2H8V1H6v2H5c-1.11 0-1.99.9-1.99 2L3 19c0 1.1.89 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2h-1V1h-2zm3 18H5V8h14v11z">
                    </path>
                </svg><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root css-w0pj6f"></span></button></div>
        <fieldset aria-hidden="true" class="MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline css-igs3ac">
            <legend class="css-14lo706"><span>Data di nascita</span></legend>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

The main issue is that the helpertext doesn't shows and all the graphics style is not loaded. Another issue is that the placeholder text and the input system is different.
The one that is working correctly permit to insert the text freely, instead the other force to fill the data as separate fields.
Here an image of the difference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What are the versions of  `mui` and the  `date-pickers`?

Comment: @mui/material: 5.12.3
@mui/x-date-pickers: 5.0.0-alpha.2

That's because I'm using formik-mui-x-date-pickers .

I tried to install the @mui/x-date-pickers 6.5.0 and I have locally the same behaviour as the production. No helpertext, no graphics applied and same text input in separate fields

Comment: @DobromirKirov thank you it was related to an old version used by formik-mui-x-date-pickers